Convergence of fixed point iteration
i am currently trying to understand in which cases the fixed point iteration for a function converges.
I know that if $x^*$ is a fixpoint of $f$ and
\begin{equation}
|f'(x^*)|<1,
\end{equation}
then there is a closed neighborhood of $x^*$, where the fixed point iteration converges. Also, if
\begin{equation}
|f'(x)|<1\,\forall x\in [x^*-\delta,x^*+\delta],
\end{equation}
then the iteration converges to $x^*$ for all starting points $x_0\in [x^*-\delta,x^*+\delta]$ right?
But does $|f'(x^*)|>1$ imply, that the iteration will definitly fail? Or could there be any case, where the iteration reaches the the fixed point "by accident"?

You can certainly reach the fixed point by accident, for example if you start there. There's a more general criterion if, for example, $f$ is a linear transformation acting on a vector space, which is often used to analyze the behavior of an arbitrary $f$ near a fixed point.

So the derivative won’t tell me, if the iteration will fail, it will only tell me, when it will definitely converge, right?

A simple example is $x=x^2$, you can see that the fixed point iteration converges to zero if $x_0\in[-1+\delta,1-\delta]$ for any $\delta\in(0,1/2)$. However, in this case $|f'(x)|=|2x|\ge1$.

Great example, thank you! Is there another way to prove divergence of the fixed point iteration by considering the derivative?

Not in general, since the above example shows that the algorithm can converge even if $|f'(x)|\ge 1$

That said, for this example if $|x_0|>1$ then $|f'(x)|\ge 1$ and the algorithm diverges

Thank you so much! Maybe another thought on this: What if $|f‘(x)|>1, \forall x\in [x^-\delta,x^+\delta]$? Similar to the case you described where $|x_0|>1$. Would this imply divergence?

No problem! Again the above example has that property but converges, so $|f'(x)|>1$ cannot imply divergence in general. Take $\delta =1/4$ and the interval is then $[-3/4,3/4]$, so $|f'(x)|>1$ on the whole interval and the algorithm still converges

Maybe i am overlooking something, but $|f‘(x)|\geq 1, \forall x\in [-0.5,0.5]$, so $|f‘(x)|\ngtr 1, \forall x\in [-1+\delta, 1-\delta]$. That’s different from what I described isn’t it?

I thought about something like $f(x)=2x$ with $|f‘(x)=2>1$ everywhere for which the iteration will diverge for every $x_0\neq 0$.

Exactly, that's why I specified $\delta\in(0,1/2)$, which makes the interval large enough to exclude that case. Your second example does work in the sense that $|f'(x)|\ge1$ and the algorithm diverges. However, the example I've given shows that $|f'(x)|\ge1$ does not always imply divergence
